# Is it possible to get element text using POCO XPath

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, poco, poco-libraries

Xml:

```
<root>
  <headers>
          <aaa>111</aaa>
          <bbb>222</bbb> 
  </headers>
</root>
```

Some of xpaths that I tried (either not found or value is empty):

```
/root/headers/bbb value[]       
/root/headers/aaa value[]       
/root/headers/bbb/text() could not be found.        
/root/headers/aaa/text() could not be found.        
//bbb value[]           
//bbb/text() could not be found.            
//bbb[1] could not be found.        
//aaa[0] value[]        
/root/headers/bbb[1] could not be found.        
/root/headers/aaa[0] value[]
```

Code:

```
Poco::XML::XMLString xmlPath(xPath);
Poco::XML::Node* node = rootNode->getNodeByPath(xmlPath);
std::string value = node->nodeValue();
```

Is it possible to get 111 or 222 values by using XPath?

Comment: Did you try `/root/headers/bbb/text()[1]`?

Comment: @PeterK I did try /root/headers/bbb/text()[1] or /root/headers/bbb/text()[0] - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
//root//headers//text()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string value;
Poco::XML::Node* node = rootNode->getNodeByPath("//aaa"); // the Node is the Element aaa
if (node && node->firstChild() && node->firstChild()->nodeType() == Poco::XML::Node::TEXT_NODE)
    value = node->firstChild()->nodeValue(); // firstChild of the Element is the Text node, nodeValue() give its text (you should also Poco::trim() it)

// same for "//bbb"
```

Comment: I'd like to know why someone vote for my first answer as not useful while it is the only way to do what is required : to get the text inside an element with Poco (which doesn't support XPath but a simpler syntax to get element nodes or attribute values), you have to get the first child (expected as text node) of the element. I had the same question and found this answer.